# How to use data in one Android fragment to populate another fragment within the same Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I have an app with a single activity that contains 7 fragments. In one of the fragments, I have a ListView that uses an Adapter to get a list of people from the database. I would like to be able to touch one of the people in "Fragment A" and have the app switch to "Fragment B", and have the information about that person populated in Fragment B.

I already have most of this working. My Fragment A reads the database and gets a list of people. If I hard code a name in Fragment B, it will successfully read the database and populate the information about the person.

What I am having trouble figuring out is, (1) how to isolate an individual row in Fragment A in order to place an onclicklistener on it, and (2) how to send that name from Fragment A to be picked up by Fragment B.

In Fragment A I have:

```
public class PeopleList extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private DatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter = mySimpleCursorAdapter;
    private Cursor personCursor;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.peoplelayout, container, false);
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        personCursor = myDBHelper.getPeopleCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"_id", "firstname", "lastname"};
        int toViews = {R.id.person_id, R.id.person_firstname, R.id.person_lastname};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.people_layout, personCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.people_row);
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);
        myDBHelper.close();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Fragment B is similar to Fragment A, except I [want to] pass in the person ID

```
demographicDataCursor = myDBHelper.getDemographicDataCursor(person_id);
```

However, currently, the person_id is hard coded for each person I want to view.

Like I said, I'm not sure how to isolate each person in the ListView of Fragment A in order to attach an onclicklistener to it, and how to send the person_id to Fragment B. I am aware of intents, but I have read several pages that say not to use intents when communicating from one fragment to another within the same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PeopleList set `OnItemClickListener` on `ListView` and on click of item put values to `Bundle` and Add that `Bundle` to `Fragment` and Done transaction of Fragment.

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mySimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("firstname"));
        FragmentB frag = new FragmentB();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("name",name);
        frag.setArguments(b);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.yourContainer, frag)
                        .commit();
     }
});
```

Now in `FragmentB` receive the values from `Bundle` as below

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        String name = getArguments().getString("name", "");
        if(!name.equals("")){
            Log.e("Name", name);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't know about "setOnItemClickListener". I'm not sure where you got the "name" value from in your example. It looks like the only useful item I have access to in the "onItemClick" method is the position. How do I go about getting the actual name out?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add name variable. I have edited my answer please check and Let me know if this works @Brian

Comment: I'm not sure if you can help with this or not, but when I follow your example, I get an "addView(View) not supported in AdapterView". I believe I get this on the line "getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.yourContainer, frag).commit();". Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your Logcat please. Did you see which line is causing the error?? @ Brian

Comment: I put the logcat here: http://pastebin.com/w9ihH4bt . It does not say what line the error is on, but it is on the line I mentioned above. It is because my R.id.yourContainer is a ListView. I tried wrapping the ListView in another container and changed beginTransaction().add to beginTransaction.replace() but all it did was add to the view already there.

Comment: R.id.yourContainer must be a layout in your Fragments Parent Activity xml in which Fragments can be add or replace. @Brian